# How to track a specific Button from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview

I have a gridview with template button in it each row
each button fires an `Onclick` event.

i need to track the row of the pressed button.
if i want , lets say colorize the background , how should i do it?

```
<asp:GridView ID="OrdersGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="DeleteOrder" runat="server" BackColor="Red" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Text="מחק" OnClick="DeleteOrder_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderHost" HeaderText="OrderName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderId" Visible="False" />
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

The event is empty.

```
protected void DeleteOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: You may want to specify which langage you're using.

Comment: C# , edited tags.

Comment: Are you using UWP?

Comment: Does this not work ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I mean are you developing a UWP, WPF, or Web application?

Comment: Can you atleast share us some of your code?

Comment: Oh , my bad , Asp.net ; and there is no code, 
i have Onclick function which should Get the index of the pressed button from a simple gridview , Edited with the Gridview code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from your comment, you just want to get the index of your `GridView`.

```
protected void DeleteOrder_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  Button btn = (Button)sender;
  GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
  //Get the Row Index by calling row.RowIndex;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Perfect! 
just if you can explain what 'NamingContainer' is, it'll be great!

Comment: What `NamingContainer` returns is the topmost container of your that inherits the `INamingContainer` interface. It's kind of the same with `Parent`, the difference with Parent is that it only gets the immediate parent in the control tree.